# Area under the curve sin(x) over the interval $[0,2\pi ]$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$\int_{0}^{2\pi }\sin(x)dx = 0$
While the integral equals zero, the area is obviously positive.
When should i accept this as a solution and when not?

Comment: How is the area positive? Try drawing out the graph

Comment: The area below the x-axis is usually considered negative area, while the area above the x-axis is considered positive area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral computes the *signed* area, which is $0$. Essentially, the "negative" when $x \in [\pi, 2\pi]$ cancels out the "positive" when $x \in [0, \pi]$.

If you want the area in a purely geometric sense, you want to integrate $\int_{0}^{2\pi} |\sin x| dx = 4$.

Answer (score 0):

Or integrate where it's above the x-axis,  like:  $$\int_0^\pi\sin(x) dx=-\cos (\pi)+\cos (0)=2$$
as $\sin $ goes from $0$ to $1$ and back down to  $0$ on $[0,\pi] $.